# Redshift regexp_substr - extract data from a JSON type format

Tags: regex, amazon-redshift

Help much appreciated - I have a field in Redshift giving data of the form:

```
{\"frequencyCapList\":[{\"frequencyCapped\":true,\"frequencyCapPeriodCount\":1,\"frequencyCapPeriodType\":\"DAYS\",\"frequencyCapCount\":501}]}
```

What I would like to do is parse this cleanly as the output of a Redshift query into some columns like:

```
Frequency Cap Period Count | Frequency Cap Period Type | Frequency Cap Count
1                          |           DAYS            |    501
```

I believe I need to use the regexp_subst function to achieve this but I cannot work out the syntax to get the required output :(

Thanks in advance for any assistance,
Carter

Answer (score 2):

Here you go

```
select json_extract_path_text(json_extract_array_element_text(json_extract_path_text(replace('{\"frequencyCapList\":[{\"frequencyCapped\":true,\"frequencyCapPeriodCount\":1,\"frequencyCapPeriodType\":\"DAYS\",\"frequencyCapCount\":501}]}','\\',''),'frequencyCapList'),0),'frequencyCapPeriodCount');
```

just replace the last string with each one you want to extract!

Comment: Thanks for helping out! I copied this directly into Redshift though and received an error 'Invalid operation: syntax error at or near "frequencyCapList" Position: 249;'

Comment: dont forget to mark as correct answer and/or upvote if the answer is correct.

Comment: please check that you copied ok  - as its stand alone and works for me

Comment: especially make sure the escaped characters havnt been replaced in your ide etc

Comment: Trying to troubleshoot - the 'replace' function alone fails: select
replace('{\"frequencyCapList\":[{\"frequencyCapped\":true,\"frequencyCapPeriodCount\":1,\"frequencyCapPeriodType\":\"DAYS\",\"frequencyCapCount\":501}]}','\\','') -- gives Invalid operation: unterminated quoted string at or near "'\','') ) " Position: 162

Comment: try replacing the double \\ with just \? the one you pasted above works perfectly on my ide (i use datagrip on windows)

Comment: :( I believe you haha - I think the issue is the very end of the replace function:  ,'\\','')  -- I think in my Redshift interface '\' is an escape character so combining \' removes the terminating quote?

Comment: Possibly related?: https://github.com/databricks/spark-redshift/issues/215

Comment: maybe those \'s are not even in your data? and your ide has added them? try running against your data source directly but without the replace()

Comment: I tried the above but still no luck :( Thanks for your help though! I think the \'s are in the data but the query engine gets confused by the presence of \'s within my query, which is an annoying combination :)

Comment: If you know regex I think this should be possible by extracting text between e.g 'frequencyCapped' and 'frequency' ; between 'frequencyCapPeriodType' and 'frequency etc. but I don't know the syntax for this